# Extract number + letter combination from string

Tags: regex

I'm intrested in extracting `c8127c6ea6a44c109b5e35ce61cd4b0096a9c6dc` from a string that looks like this:

`?t=c8127c6ea6a44c109b5e35ce61cd4b0096a9c6dc'`

Here is my attempt at capturing the result in to a group.

`?t=([a-e]\d+)'`

Could anyone point me in the right direction, since this obviously isn't working?

http://regexr.com?383s6

Comment: Why not just split on the = and trim the '?

Comment: What language?  Many languages have a query string parser

Comment: @ernie Because this is only a portion of the string.

Comment: You should have shown the full string.  As @ExplosionPills mentions, if this is a query string, using an appropriate library/function is probably much better than regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wanna put the \d in the [a-e] block and escape the ?:

```
\?t=([a-f\d]+)'
```

(and I assume you're looking for hexadecimal so it should be a-f?)

Comment: Might you also need to escape the single-quote, depending on the environment?  (Edit - I'm testing this with replacement in sed, so yes, I would.)

Comment: @kbshimmyo it's not due to sed you have to escape the single-quote - you're needing to escape it due to the shell environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
\?t=([a-e0-9]+)'
```

OR usig negation:

```
\?t=([^']+)'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby language you can try [Rubular tool](http://www.rubular.com) online to test your regular expressions.

```
\?t=(\w+)'
```

should do the match.